# Force Firefox and Chrome to reload page including all graphics, even favicon

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, cache, refresh

Using the latest Firefox and Chrome on macOS.

I can refresh a page using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. This doesn't reload any images if the browser thinks its cached version is still OK (even if it isn't).

I can also use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to force a refresh, this discards any cached images and reloads them as well. Except for the favicon, for some reason it keeps loading the favicon from its cache, even if I know it has been changed (on the server).

Is there a way to enforce Firefox or Chrome to absolutely reload **everything** for a particular page, including resources such as favicon.ico?

Of course I can delete my entire browser cache and history, or completely disable caching in the browser's settings altogether, but that's typically not what I want. I just want it to reload everything for that particular page, once.

Comment: If you're getting to the page from a saved shortcut, delete the shortcut, then ctrl-F5, then manually enter the web page URL.  Save a copy in the clipboard before you try all that, though.  I'm pretty sure that the favicon.ico file is saved with the shortcut itself, which is why it is not re-downloading.

Comment: For what it's worth, I used to use (many years ago) a specialized program I'd found on the net somewhere that went out to every single URL in my favorites, marked the dead links, and downloaded the favicons if available.  I seem to recall looking for it not too long ago, but couldn't find it again.

Comment: @BillHileman The favicon being saved along with a shortcut makes sense, yes. However it also happens for sites that are not in my bookmarks. I guess it has to do with Firefox keeping a history of recently visited links and showing them with a favicon as well (in the History > Recently Closed Tabs menu).
It gets even weirder because if I open a Private Tab, and open that same URL, it *does* load the correct favicon. But then when I open a new regular window, and open the same URL there as well, it's showing the old favicon again!

Comment: Not exactly what you ask for, but *Clear Browsing Data* Firefox add-on makes it convenient to clear cache, form data etc. with one click -- however, it does clear *all* the cache, not just one site.